# Javascript content to HTML content converter

Tags: javascript, html, spidermonkey

Take a Javascript file with the following code

```
var pzt = document.createElement('iframe');
pzt.src = 'http://www.abc.com';
pzt.style.width = '100px';
if (!document.getElementById('pzt')) {
    document.write('<div id=\'pzt\'></div>');
    document.getElementById('pzt').appendChild(pzt);
}
```

I would like to get the result of the above javascript as an html file with the code

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="pzt">
<iframe src="http://www.abc.com" width="100"> </iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried spidermonkey but there is no use. is there any other way to process or convert the javascript file to get the html as specified above. Thanks.

Comment: Use the value of `document.body.outerHTML` once the above is done?

Comment: Do you want to get it from the browser or from command line?

Comment: @avetisk from command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution with Node.js, I can't tell you one with SpiderMonkey. Like Node.js, SpiderMonkey has no browser env as it's only a JavaScript engine. But Node.js has many library for simulating a browser env. Thus I suggest you to use Node.js instead of SpiderMonkey.

1. `npm install domino` (you will need [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/))
2. Change your js source (let's say `dom.js`) to:

```js
var domino = require('domino');
var window = domino.createWindow();
var document = window.document;
var pzt = document.createElement('iframe');
pzt.src = 'http://www.abc.com';
pzt.style.width = '100px';
if (!document.getElementById('pzt')) {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div id=\'pzt\'></div>';
    document.getElementById('pzt').appendChild(pzt);
}
console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

1. Then `node dom.js > out.html`